# Handlebars - what is "depth0 is undefined"?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

When using Handlebars.js, what is "depth0 is undefined"?

I get an error as follows:

```
depth0 is undefined
[Break On This Error]
```

Comment: Actually, a perfectly valid question, Google finds it in response to "depth0 is undefined". Means that the template being rendered is passed with incorrect JSON. Worth answering.

Comment: agree! just spent 30 minutes digging through source code just to find out that `$("#that").html(form())` is bad, where `$("that").html(form({}))` works.

Comment: Should someone find this via google, v1.1+ should not error if no context value is passed to the template function.